# Elastic search nested object alternative

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a Elastic index structure like this below,

```
"-source":{
    "file_name":"abc.ex",
    "file_format":"ex",
    "created_time":"2016-05-11"
    "mime_type":"xyz",
    "metadata":{
          "meta_id":"11222",
          "description":"xyzz",
          "profile":[
                  {"key_id":"1"
                   "value":2
                   },
                  {"key_id":"2",
                   "value":44
                   }...]
                 }
            }
```

In profile I should map each key_id to its value.Ex this query  key_id = "1" AND value = 2 should match. For this reason I mapped profile as nested object like below.

```
{"metadata":{
    "properties":{
      "meta_id":{"type":"string"}...
      "profile":{
               "type":"nested",
               "properties":{
                      "key_id":{"type":"string"},
                      "value":{"type":"string"}
                        }}}
```

}

Is there any other way instead of making it nested object?Since it treats it as a different document , When i do a simple query string search

{'query': {'bool':{'must':[{'query_string': {'query': u'*abc*', 'fields': ['metadata.profile.value','metadata.profile.meta-id']}}]}}}

it excludes the nested document(metadata.profile.value), but I want them to be included. And what does this mean "To add, change, or delete a nested document, the whole document must be reindexed" ?.

Comment: Can you show the query you're making that "excludes" the nested documents?

Comment: {'query': {'bool':{'must':[{'query_string': {'query': u'*abc*', 'fields': ['metadata.profile.value','metadata.profile.meta-id']}}]}}}. It doesn't search "abc" in metadata.profile.value  , since it is nested

Comment: Update your question with the query, it's more legible

Comment: @Val Updated  the question with query